# How use c++ and c# dll in firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Sorry I am new in firefox addon develop.
Can you help me with using c++ dll in my firefox addon. I know about js-ctypes, but I can't use c++ dll directly in js-ctypes. How can include  c++ dll in my addon?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Firefox addons are supposed to be platform independent. So DLLs are out.

Comment: https://github.com/ochameau/jscpptypes this works for C++ I havent used it myself yet though. I also did COM which is C++ Windows API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Examples/Using_COM_from_js-ctypes C# is possible too I haven't cracked it yet though, I haven't had the opportunity.

Comment: **About convert COM code to C code:**                                                  Need I get source code of c# from dll to use command:                                                                           **$ cl ole32.lib test.cpp**                                                                                                Or I can directly use dll in that command?

Comment: You can directly use it but im not sure how. I started investigating how to do c# here: https://github.com/trueinteractions/tint2/issues/161#issuecomment-148879630  If you want to use the COM code without a dll, you would follow the link i posted in my previous comment. If you want to convert your c# dll to a c dll, then to use that you would follow this article here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/ctypes.open#Custom_Native_File